# Proving Logical Equivalence - $\lnot(( p \leftrightarrow q )) \equiv (p \leftrightarrow ¬( q )))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I'm trying to prove that the LHS and RHS of the following are logically equivalent:

$\lnot(( p \leftrightarrow q ) \equiv (p \leftrightarrow ¬( q )))$

This is what I've managed to get so far, but I'm not sure where I can go from there...

$≡ ¬(( p\to  q ) ∧ ( q\to  p ))]$

$≡ ¬(((¬p) ∨ q ) ∧ ((¬q) ∨ p )))$

$≡ ¬((¬p) ∨ q ) ∨ ¬((¬q) ∨ p ))$

$≡ (p ∧ (¬q)) ∨ (q ∧ (¬p))$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience.

Answer (score 1):

All your work, thus far, is correct.

You might want to work on the RHS of the proposed equivalence:

$$(p\iff (-q)) \equiv ((p\to (\lnot q)) \land ((\lnot q) \to p)$$

$$\equiv ((\lnot p) \lor (\lnot q)) \land (q \lor p)$$

$$\equiv ((\lnot p) \land (q\lor p))\lor ((\lnot q)\land (q\lor p))\tag{distributive law}$$

$$\equiv (((\lnot p) \land q) \lor ((\lnot p)\land p))) \lor (((\lnot q) \land q) \lor((\lnot q) \land p)))\tag{dist. law $\times 2$}$$

$$\equiv ((\lnot p) \land q) \lor F \lor F \lor ((\lnot q) \land p$$

$$\equiv ((\lnot p) \land q)\lor ((\lnot q) \land p)$$

$$\equiv (q \land (\lnot p)) \lor (p \land (\lnot q)) \tag{commutativity}$$

$$\equiv (p \land (\lnot q)) \lor (q \land (\lnot p))\tag{commutativity}$$

Comment: Good. Yes, sometimes you want to work on both the LHS and the RHS, and try and 'meet in the middle'.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, did it with RHS like you did, but got a final answer of [ ¬ ( q <-> p ) ] instead of [ ¬ ( p <-> q ) ]. Is it reversible (i.e. basically the same) or maybe I might've done something wrong?

Comment: Hi, Bandolero.  Sorry for taking so long to get back to you.  Your result is correct, because $(q\iff p)\equiv (p\iff q)$ by commutativity.  So the negation of one is equivalent to the negation of the other.

Comment: What I tried to do wrt this question, was accept your correct work for which you found the LHS $\equiv \big((p \land (\lnot q)) \lor (q \land (\lnot p))\big)$, and I verified that the RHS $\equiv\big( (p \land (\lnot q)) \lor (q \land (\lnot p))\big)$.  Therefore, the LHS $\equiv$ RHS.